# chkrootkit false positives?

Tags: 18.04, security, rstudio, chkrootkit

I've just run chkrootkit on my laptop running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and everything is in the clear except the following:

```
    Searching for suspicious files and dirs, it may take a while... 
The following suspicious files and directories were found: 
/usr/lib/jvm/.java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo /usr/lib/debug/.build-id 
/usr/lib/rstudio/www/.gitignore 
/usr/lib/rstudio/resources/templates/.gitignore 
/lib/modules/5.0.0-27-generic/vdso/.build-id 
/lib/modules/5.0.0-29-generic/vdso/.build-id
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id 
/lib/modules/5.0.0-27-generic/vdso/.build-id 
/lib/modules/5.0.0-29-generic/vdso/.build-id
```

Are any or all of these warnings false positives? I have done a fairly thorough search for each warning and come up empty. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those files are tagged "suspicious", because they're "hidden" (that is, their names begin with a dot). Inspect them with `ls -Adl` and `less`. Use `dpkg -S` to see if the files/dirs belong to a package.

Comment: Thank you, waltinator. According to dpkg -S, the suspicious files above are part of a package. Is it safe to leave it at that and white-list these files?

Comment: Btw.,  I take it chkrootkit marks any unknown hidden files. And there seem to be a something missing above. To inspect a hidden file, you need to use ls -al, "-a" for all, right?